# how to transform the method from Firestore to Realtime Database

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

im trying to convert database from firestore to firebase rtdb, by the tutorial I see the following code:

```
  static Stream<List<Message>> getMessages(String idUser) =>
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('chats/$idUser/messages')
          .orderBy(MessageField.createdAt, descending: true)
          .snapshots()
          .transform(Utils.transformer(Message.fromJson));
```

here is the code I updated:

```
    static Stream<List<Message>> getMessages(String idUser) =>
  FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .ref()
      .child('chats/$idUser/messages')
      .onValue
      .map((message) =>
      message.snapshot.children.map((e) =>
          Message.fromJson(e.value as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList());
```

is it correct and how to add method orderBy, or please share me the correct code which has same value as the one for firestore, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database only support ascending ordering, so you can map `.orderBy(MessageField.createdAt, descending: true)` from Firestore to Realtime Database.

The closest you can get is:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .ref()
    .child('chats/$idUser/messages')
    .orderByChild(MessageField.createdAt)
    .onValue
    ...
```

And then reversing the results in your application code.

Also see the FlutterFire documentation on [querying Realtime Database](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/usage#querying).

Comment: Hi Frank, sorry to bother you again, could you please tell me how to reverse the map order in my case, im just new to code world, and search for the solution, so if I get the Stream<List<Message>, it is already the stream of message, and how can I sort the oder with createdAt?